# Compare Two Custom Post Types Using The Same Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, loop

I have two post types, *courses* and *testimonials*, sharing the same taxonomies. What I am looking to accomplish is to check whether a course is in the same category as a testimonial. Then display if it is, keeping in mind they could have more than one category each.

I am currently able to check which categories they are in using `get_the_term_list()` but can't figure out how to go about comparing them to one another.

What I need is to be able to check is if the categories checked off in pm_course(post-type) is the same as course_testimonials(post-type). If they have the same category then I want to display the testimonial, if not I want to do nothing.

Really a basic if else statement but I can't seem to find a way to see if the checked categories are the same in both.

Comment: Questions like this are usually easier to grasp if you provide some [simplified] example of actual data.

Comment: What kind of information do you need? I'm not able to paste the plugin code here since it is quite large.

Comment: This is how I am assigning the taxonomies to both post types ... `register_taxonomy( 'course_type', 
    array('pm_courses', 'course_testimonials'), 
    $args );
` and I am able to determine what categories are being used on each by adding `echo get_the_term_list( $id, 'course_type', '', '</br>', '' );` to my single-pm_course.php page

Comment: You should edit your question to add information. I didn't meant code, I meant human-friendly example. In line of "I have course called _Dogs_ and testimonial _Woof_, I need..."

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `get_the_term_list()` as it returns an HTML string, which makes comparing more difficult.

Use `wp_get_post_terms()` ([Codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)) instead. It can return an array, and then you can use something like `array_intersect()` to get the terms that match.

Your code should look something like this (I haven't tested this):

```
$course_terms = wp_get_post_terms($course_post_id, 'course_type'. array('fields'=>'slug'));
$testimonial_terms = wp_get_post_terms($testimonial_post_id, 'course_type'. array('fields'=>'slug')); 
$matches = array_intersect($course_terms, $testimonial_terms);
if (count($matches) > 0) echo "matching terms";
```

Comment: No matter what I do it just returns empty arrays?